# BitConverter.GetBytes in place

Tags: c#, arrays, byte

I need to get values in `UInt16` and `UInt64` as `Byte[]`. At the moment I am using `BitConverter.GetBytes`, but this method gives me a new array instance each time.

I would like to use a method that allow me to "copy" those values to already existing arrays, something like:

```
.ToBytes(UInt64 value, Byte[] array, Int32 offset);
.ToBytes(UInt16 value, Byte[] array, Int32 offset);
```

I have been taking a look to the .NET source code with ILSpy, but I not very sure how this code works and how can I safely modify it to fit my requirement:

```
public unsafe static byte[] GetBytes(long value)
{
    byte[] array = new byte[8];
    fixed (byte* ptr = array)
    {
            *(long*)ptr = value;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Which would be the right way of accomplishing this?

Updated: I cannot use unsafe code. It should not create new array instances.

Comment: That is what I was doing. I want to prevent the creation of new arrays each time I use BitConverter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
static unsafe void ToBytes(ulong value, byte[] array, int offset)
{
    fixed (byte* ptr = &array[offset])
        *(ulong*)ptr = value;
}
```

Usage:

```
byte[] array = new byte[9];
ToBytes(0x1122334455667788, array, 1);
```

You can set offset only in bytes.

If you want managed way to do it:

```
static void ToBytes(ulong value, byte[] array, int offset)
{
    byte[] valueBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
    Array.Copy(valueBytes, 0, array, offset, valueBytes.Length);
}
```

Or you can fill values by yourself:

```
static void ToBytes(ulong value, byte[] array, int offset)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        array[offset + i] = (byte)value;
        value >>= 8;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, won't this blow up in a bad way (memory corruption) if you happen to put it starting at index 8 of a 9 byte array? Also, are unaligned writes guaranteed to work on - for example - ARM?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yes, it would blow. I presume author knows what he does. If under ARM you consider WinRT, then this code just wouldn't compile.

Comment: I just realized I cannot mark my assembly as unsafe, so I cannot use unsafe code. Could you explain how this code would blow up for reference?

Comment: I see, but the whole point if this is avoiding creating new arrays.

Comment: @vtortola Added method without arrays.

Comment: +1 for the regular loop answer. It's straight forward, and has the potential upside of letting you choose endian-ness of the result, the other methods will always use native byte order.

Comment: Very nice indeed, that is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 5):

Now that .NET has added `Span<T>` support for better working with arrays, unmanaged memory, etc without excess allocations, they've also added [System.Buffer.Binary.BinaryPrimitives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.binary.binaryprimitives?view=netcore-3.1).

This works as you would want, e.g. [WriteUInt64BigEndian](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.binary.binaryprimitives.writeuint64bigendian?view=netcore-3.1#System_Buffers_Binary_BinaryPrimitives_WriteUInt64BigEndian_System_Span_System_Byte__System_UInt64_) has this signature:

```
public static void WriteUInt64BigEndian (Span<byte> destination, ulong value);
```

which avoids allocating.

Answer (score 2):

You say you want to avoid creating new arrays and you cannot use unsafe. Either use Ulugbek Umirov's answer with cached arrays (be careful with threading issues) or:

```
static void ToBytes(ulong value, byte[] array, int offset) {
 unchecked {
  array[offset + 0] = (byte)(value >> (8*7));
  array[offset + 1] = (byte)(value >> (8*6));
  array[offset + 2] = (byte)(value >> (8*5));
  array[offset + 3] = (byte)(value >> (8*4));
  //...
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you wish to avoid, for some reason, creating any temporary new arrays. And you also want to avoid unsafe code.

You could pin the object and then copy to the array.

```
public static void ToBytes(ulong value, byte[] array, int offset) 
{
    GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(value, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    try
    {
        Marshal.Copy(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), array, offset, 8);
    }
    finally
    {
        handle.Free();
    }
}
```

Comment: I kind of expect now that the next requirement to be added will be to avoid pinning!  ;-)

Comment: I interpreted his remark in such a way that his assembly is not under full trust.

Answer (score 0):

BinaryWriter can be a good solution.

```
var writer = new BinaryWriter(new MemoryStream(yourbuffer, youroffset, yourbuffer.Length-youroffset));
writer.Write(someuint64);
```

It's useful when you need to convert a lot of data into a buffer continuously

```
var writer = new BinaryWriter(new MemoryStream(yourbuffer));
foreach(var value in yourints){
    writer.Write(value);
}
```

or when you just want to write to a file, that's the best case to use BinaryWriter.

```
var writer = new BinaryWriter(yourFileStream);
foreach(var value in yourints){
    writer.Write(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that stumbles across this.
If Big Endian support is NOT required and Unsafe is allowed then I've written a library specifically to minimize GC allocations during serialization for single threaded serializers such as when serializing across TCP sockets.

Note: supports Little Endian ONLY example X86 / X64 (might add big endian support some day)

https://github.com/tcwicks/ChillX/tree/master/src/ChillX.Serialization

In the process also re-wrote BitConverter so that it works similar to BitPrimitives but with a lot of extras such as supporting arrays as well.
https://github.com/tcwicks/ChillX/blob/master/src/ChillX.Serialization/BitConverterExtended.cs

```
Random rnd = new Random();
RentedBuffer<byte> buffer = RentedBuffer<byte>.Shared.Rent(BitConverterExtended.SizeOfUInt64
    + (20 * BitConverterExtended.SizeOfUInt16)
    + (20 * BitConverterExtended.SizeOfTimeSpan)
    + (10 * BitConverterExtended.SizeOfSingle);
UInt64 exampleLong = long.MaxValue;
int startIndex = 0;
startIndex += BitConverterExtended.GetBytes(exampleLong, buffer.BufferSpan, startIndex);

UInt16[] shortArray = new UInt16[20];
for (int I = 0; I < shortArray.Length; I++) { shortArray[I] = (ushort)rnd.Next(0, UInt16.MaxValue); }
//When using reflection / expression trees CLR cannot distinguish between UInt16 and Int16 or Uint64 and Int64 etc...
//Therefore Uint methods are renamed.
startIndex += BitConverterExtended.GetBytesUShortArray(shortArray, buffer.BufferSpan, startIndex);

TimeSpan[] timespanArray = new TimeSpan[20];
for (int I = 0; I < timespanArray.Length; I++) { timespanArray[I] = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(rnd.Next(0, int.MaxValue)); }
startIndex += BitConverterExtended.GetBytes(timespanArray, buffer.BufferSpan, startIndex);

float[] floatArray = new float[10];
for (int I = 0; I < floatArray.Length; I++) { floatArray[I] = MathF.PI * rnd.Next(short.MinValue, short.MaxValue); }
startIndex += BitConverterExtended.GetBytes(floatArray, buffer.BufferSpan, startIndex);

//Do stuff with buffer and then
buffer.Return();
//Or
buffer = null;
//and let RentedBufferContract do this automatically
```

The underlying problem is actually two fold. Even if you use bitprimitives we still have the issue of the byte array buffers that we are writing to / reading from. The issue is further compounded if we have lots of array fields T[] for example int[]

Using standard BitConverter leads to situations like 80% time spent in GC.
bitprimitives is a much better but we still need to manage the byte[] buffers. If we create one byte[] buffer for each int in an array of 1000 ints that is 1000 byte[4] arrays to garbage collect which means rent a buffer big enough for all 1000 ints (int[4000]) from ArrayPool but then we have to manage returning these buffers.
Further complicating it is the fact that we have to track the length of each buffer that is actually used since ArrayPool will return arrays that are larger than that which is requested. System.Buffers.ArrayPool.Shared.Rent(4000); will usually return a byte[4096] or maybe even a byte[8192]

This serialization code:
uses a wrappers around ArrayPool in order make its usage transparent:
https://github.com/tcwicks/ChillX/blob/master/src/ChillX.Core/Structures/ManagedPool.cs

For managing renting and returning of ArrayPool buffers:

https://github.com/tcwicks/ChillX/blob/master/src/ChillX.Core/Structures/RentedBuffer.cs

With operator overloads on + operator to automatically assign from Span

For preventing memory leaks and also managing use and forget style guaranteed return of rented buffers:

https://github.com/tcwicks/ChillX/blob/master/src/ChillX.Core/Structures/RentedBufferContract.cs

Example:

```
//Assume ArrayProperty_Long is a long[] array.
RentedBuffer<long> ClonedArray = RentedBuffer<long>.Shared.Rent(ArrayProperty_Long.Length);
ClonedArray += ArrayProperty_Long;
```

ClonedArray will be returned to ArrayPool.Shared automatically when ClonedArray goes out of scope (handled by RentedBufferContract).
Or call ClonedArray.Return();

p.s. Any feedback is much appreciated.

Following benchmarks compare performance using rented buffers and this serializer implementation versus using MessagePack without rented buffers. Messagepack if micro benchmarked is a faster serializer. This performance difference is purely due to reducing GC collection overheads by pooling / renting buffers.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmarking ChillX Serializer: Test Object: Data class with 31 properties / fields of different types inlcuding multiple arrays of different types
Num Reps: 50000  -  Array Size: 256
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Entity Size bytes: 20,678  -  Count: 00,050,000  -  Threads: 01  -  Entities Per Second: 00,025,523  -  Mbps: 503.32  -  Time: 00:00:01.9589880
Entity Size bytes: 20,678  -  Count: 00,050,000  -  Threads: 01  -  Entities Per Second: 00,026,129  -  Mbps: 515.26  -  Time: 00:00:01.9135886
Entity Size bytes: 20,678  -  Count: 00,050,000  -  Threads: 01  -  Entities Per Second: 00,026,291  -  Mbps: 518.46  -  Time: 00:00:01.9018027

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmarking MessagePack Serializer: Test Object: Data class with 31 properties / fields of different types inlcuding multiple arrays of different types
Num Reps: 50000  -  Array Size: 256
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Entity Size bytes: 19,811  -  Count: 00,050,000  -  Threads: 01  -  Entities Per Second: 00,012,386  -  Mbps: 234.01  -  Time: 00:00:04.0668261
Entity Size bytes: 19,811  -  Count: 00,050,000  -  Threads: 01  -  Entities Per Second: 00,012,285  -  Mbps: 232.10  -  Time: 00:00:04.0523329
Entity Size bytes: 19,811  -  Count: 00,050,000  -  Threads: 01  -  Entities Per Second: 00,012,642  -  Mbps: 238.84  -  Time: 00:00:03.9811276
```